# jQuery - Efeito de transformar texto em tag só funciona na primeira linha da tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando transformar os status da tabela em tag, consegui com jQuery porém está aplicando somente na primeira linha da tabela (gerada com PHP), as demais o texto não é substituído.

PHP

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?=$user->id_matricula?></th>
        <td><?=$user->nm_usuario?></td>
        <td><?=$user->nm_setor?></td>
        <td><?=$user->nm_cargo?></td>
        <td><?=$user->ds_login?></td>
        <td><?=$user->ds_perfil?></td>
        <td><?=$user->dt_create?></td>
        <td><?=$user->dt_update?></td>
        <td class="text-center" id="status"><?=$user->ds_status?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach?>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    var op = $("#status").text();
    switch (op) {
        case 'Ativo':
            $("#status").html('<i class="fas fa-circle fa-small-size text-success"></i>');
            break;
        case 'Inativo':
            $("#status").html('<i class="fas fa-circle fa-small-size text-warning"></i>');
            break;
        case 'Bloqueado':
            $("#status").html('<i class="fas fa-circle fa-small-size text-danger"></i>');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em HTML o  atributo `id` tem de ser único. Só podes ter 1 por página. Estás a criar ids duplicados a cada linha da tabela...

Muda esses id para classes por exemplo e no jQuery muda a lógica para iterar essas linhas:

**No HTML:**

```
class="text-center status"
```

(repara que sem o `id="..."`)

**No JavaScript/jQuery:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".status").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var op = $el.text();
    switch (op) {
      case 'Ativo':
        $el.html('<i class="fas fa-circle fa-small-size text-success"></i>');
        break;
      case 'Inativo':
        $el.html('<i class="fas fa-circle fa-small-size text-warning"></i>');
        break;
      case 'Bloqueado':
        $el.html('<i class="fas fa-circle fa-small-size text-danger"></i>');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação, funcionou perfeitamente.